# How to put a data to view list page?

Tags: laravel-backpack

I have a controller:

```
class PageCrudController extends CrudController
{

    public function search()
    {
        $res = parent::search();
        return $res;
    }

    public function setup()
    {
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | CrudPanel Basic Information
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */
        $this->crud->setModel('App\Models\Page');
        $this->crud->setRoute(config('backpack.base.route_prefix') . '/page');
        $this->crud->setEntityNameStrings('page', 'pages');
        $this->crud->setListView('vendor.backpack.crud.page.list');
        $this->search();

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | CrudPanel Configuration
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */

        // Select all roots elements with their children
        $pagesTree = collect([]);

        $roots = Page::where('parent_id', null)->get();

        $roots->each(function ($value) use(&$pagesTree) {
            $tree = $value->getDescendantsAndSelf();
            $pagesTree = $pagesTree->merge($tree);
        });
```

In the controller I have the variable `$pagesTree`. It contains sorted data. I need to show it on a view page of list instead of the default data.

`$this->crud->orderBy` is not suitable. Because of as you can see, here I have special order of items. I have got it with the help of this package https://github.com/etrepat/baum#inserting-nodes.

Comment: When you say "It contains sorted data", do you mean that `$pagesTree` contains a collection of database models, the same models that would be retrieved by `search()` except that `$pagesTree`'s collection has already be custom sorted in some fashion?

Comment: If that is the case, or its something along those lines, you could override the `search()` method in your controller and inside that, convert your `$pagesTree` data to an array return it. See `project/vendor/backpack/crud/src/PanelTraits/Search.php->getEntriesAsJsonForDatatables` for the format you need for your array. I'd personally prefer to write a trait that adds the sorting functionality and put the sort logic in there, but overriding `search()` would work